# laravel bootstrap modal errors

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a form in a  a bootstrap modal and I'm trying to show error and stop it from fading out it via ajax now it is submitting but the errors does not appear and the submit button is disabled even thought the form is submitting

js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
//login submit

$( ".registerform" ).submit(function(e ) {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/register',
        data: $('.registerform').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
},
done:function( data ) {
    if(data.fail) {
      $.each(data.errors, function( index, value ) {
        var errorDiv = '#'+index+'_error';
        $(errorDiv).addClass('required');
        $(errorDiv).empty().append(value);
      });
      $('#successMessage').empty();          
    } 
    else{
        $('#register').hide(); //hiding Reg form
        var successContent = '<div class="message"><h3>Registration Completed Successfully</h3><h4>Please Login With the Following Details</h4><div class="userDetails"><p><span>Email:</span>'+data.email+'</p><p><span>Password:********</span></p></div></div>';
      $('#successMessage').html(successContent);
    } //success
  } //done



    });
  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
$( ".registerform" ).submit();   

   });
```

Comment: try `error: function(){}`

Comment: have you tried adding it after `success:`?

Comment: Have you seen any errors in console of browser?